Compositor node output in 4.2 doesn't have Z channel that 3.6 had
This feels daft but I cannot find anything online to reference either this feature being disabled in the 4.* releases of Blender, or a setting to enable the output depth pass being added to the final composite.
I want to use the OpenEXR format with, what would be in 3.6, the z buffer option enabled, but that is also missing. I'm using Blender 4.2 here, and the blender docs for 4.2 annoyingly show the compsitor node with the Z output there.
What am I doing wrong?

See the difference in options here.


Oh, I just realised what your problem is - you don't want to save it as OpenEXR MultiLayer, just as regular OpenEXR, right? Okay, then you got a problem and the answers given here will not help. @MartynasŽiemys I completely missed the point that he wants to save the depth in an EXR non-multilayer file.

It's all confusing how EXR is implemented in Blender. If you just render to MultilayerEXR it outputs a file with multiple "layers", but if you use File Output node, there is just one of those and still it contains multiple images. I think it's the same thing as it was if you use File Output node and just add the Z there... Does it really matter? Most software supports MultilayerEXRs now...

@MartynasŽiemys It simply was not necessary to use a File Output node. Say you render an animation with hundreds of images and just want to render with Ctrl+F12, and the scene is composited from many view layers, but for further editing in some other software you only need the composite image and a depth pass, then this was easily done by compositing everything together and enabling Z Buffer in the OpenEXR options and you had hundreds of EXR files with depth pass. Now you have to choose OpenEXR MultiLayer and get hundreds of files containing all view layers which are much larger.

@MartynasŽiemys And of course, while for tasks like this you are now forced to use the File Output node, doing something like mentioned before, storing all view layers with all passes in a single multilayer file, this is a major pain in the a$$ if you explicitly want to do it with a File Output node, because there you have to connect everything manually, no automatic saving of all passes in all layers just because you use OpenEXR MultiLayer as file format.

@GordonBrinkmann I think saving to EXR could have more functionality - for example why isn't there a choice to save multiple layers with File Output node?.. I think there should also be a choose to disable main output if File Output node is used. However, it's at most slight inconvenience. If only depth pass is needed there is only one connection in the nodes and it's possible to render single view layer, if more passes are needed, nothing changed - only Z pass was removed from randomly being there on composite node. Why not normal pass?.. Why is Z special?.. Now they are all uniform.

Oh, OK, I get it. If you want to render multiple view layers each with Z pass to separate files... OK... That probably means that now you have to do more work same as if you wanted to do that with any other pass.

@MartynasŽiemys Z pass is special because other 2D software like image and video editors can use depth information for various things, whereas normal pass, UV pass etc. are often only interesting for 3D software, some of the passes maybe just for Blender compositing and nowhere else. And no, I don't mean multiple layers and each Z pass in separate files. I mean multiple layers composited into a single image and a single Z pass. In older Blender versions you can do this just by hitting F12 or Ctrl+F12 - now you get multilayer files blown up with data or are forced to use File Output.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Basically the answer by @MartynasŽiemys is completely fine, this last sentence says it all: "You can choose MultilayerEXR and all enabled passes will be saved in it."
But since you are missing the Z socket in the Composite node, I guess there is a general misunderstanding on your behalf how this works. The Z input on the Composite node is not necessary to store the actual unmodified depth pass - not in 4.2, and not in older versions like 3.6 either.
Just like the Alpha socket which is still there in newer versions, it is only necessary if you want to manipulate the pass.
Whenever you save the render result from the Image Editor with Save Image As... and choose the file format OpenEXR MultiLayer, all passes will be saved within the file withoutd the need to connect them beforehand (just like you don't need to connect something to Alpha to save an image with transparent background - it has a Use Alpha checkbox for that).
The thing is, these passes are not stored in the Composite layer, but the View Layer. Take the following example, I render a simple scene and have several non-default passes enabled. They appear on the Render Layers node as output sockets:

I did not connect any of them to the Composite node or anywhere else. Then I save the render result with Save Image As... and choose OpenEXR MultiLayer as file format:

Now I go back to the Compositor and add an Image node where I load the saved EXR file. Now this does not look very promising at first - maybe you tried it like that and got this result:

However, if I switch the Layer from Composite to View Layer, the node has a lot more outputs as you can see, all those which the Render Layers node has. With the only difference that the XYZ channels of the vector passes are stored in the RGB channels of color passes, that's why they are all yellow.

The name View Layer is the one of the layer which you rendered. And if you have multiple view layers in your scene which you all render, then they all are stored in the EXR file and you can choose which one of them you need - or use multiple Image nodes to get them all. This way you have all separate render results in the corresponding view layers' Combined output and the actual Compositor result in the Composite layer's Combined output.


Exactly what I needed, thank you very much Gordon.

You can save depth pass same way as any other pass. There is nothing special about it so it seems the developers decided to remove it from where it was for no reason at all. It's just a pass same as UV, or normal, or ambient occlusion or any one of other passes.
You can choose MultilayerEXR and all enabled passes will be saved in it.

+1, although I can imagine for someone who is not aware how the multilayer EXR stores all this data and especially how to retrieve it, this might not be so obvious - so forgive me that I gave another answer where I explained it further.
